# Haskell Bag (Multiset) implementation

Tags: haskell, syntax-error

I'm trying to implement a Haskell Bag (multiset).

So far I've got this

```
data Bag a = EmptyBag | ListBag [(a, Integer)] deriving (Eq, Show)

emptyBag :: Bag a
emptyBag = EmptyBag

add :: a -> (Bag a) -> (Bag a)
add element EmptyBag = ListBag [(element,1)]
add element (ListBag bag)
  | element `elem` map fst bag = ListBag bag -- will actually increment the count, and return the new bag.
```

I get the error

```
No instance for (Eq a)
      arising from a use of `elem'
    In the expression: element `elem` map fst bag
```

when compiling. 
Is this because you can't determine equality on two different types? How do I determine if the first element of an item in a Bag is already in the Bag?

Also, any tips on how to implement incrementing the count of a particular Item, and returning back the bag with the new (element,count) tuple?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The direct cause of your problem is that not all types are comparable for equality. You can restrict your type to only work with types that do provide an equality comparison by changing your type signature:

```
add :: Eq a => a -> Bag a -> Bag a
```

You might want to check out the [multiset-comb](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/multiset-comb) and [data-ordlist](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist) packages on Hackage for further implementation tips.

As a final note, I find the `EmptyBag` constructor a bit suspect: how does it differ from, e.g., `ListBag []`?

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking this might be the solution
I basically added the EmptyBag constructor for readability. But yes, I could have used ListBag [] instead.

Comment: The problem with your method is that `EmptyBag` and `ListBag []` are two different ways to represent the same thing. I suppose that `ListBag []` is then just invalid, but this isn't enforced by the type system and could lead to odd bugs.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the problem is that Haskell can't compare *arbitrary* elements for equality--it can only compare types that are part of the `Eq` typeclass. This makes sense: comparing certain things, like functions, is undecideable. Other languages have a notion of "reference equality" but this does not make sense in Haskell. So there are types whose values fundamentally cannot be compared for equality. You can't check if something is already in a list unless you have some way of comparing two values for equality, which is what `Eq` provides.

This means that any set (or multiset) implementation will depend on `Eq` (or some other explicit comparison function). In practice, sets tend to also depend on `Ord` for performance reasons, but since you're just using a list, don't worry about it. This also means that you can't make your multiset a Functor or Monad, but c'est la vie.

In short: you will have to constrain your types to `Eq`. So change `a -> Bag a -> Bag g` to `Eq a => a -> Bag a -> Bag a` and so on.

Since it looks like you're just doing some exercises to learn the language (I hope this doesn't come off as condescending), I'll just give you some hints for your second question.

Think recursively. First, consider a base case: how do you add an element to an empty multiset? Another base case: given a multiset with your element as the head of the list, how do you create a new, incremented multi set? Finally, the recursive case: what do you do if you have a list where the head *isn't* the element you want to increment? Once you answer all these questions, you can just write each one as a single case by pattern matching on the list and put them together to get your `add` function.

One other note: having an `EmptyBag` constructor is redundant. A list can already be empty! How is `ListBag []` different from `EmptyBag`? I would only have one constructor in this case.

So your add function will look like this:

```
add :: Eq a => a -> Bag a -> Bag a
add x (ListBag []) = ...
add x (ListBag [(x', n)]) = ...
```

Just fill in the `...` with the appropriate cases and you're all set.

As per your comment, here is some example code about how to keep the list while you recurse through it.

Basically, the main idea is simple: in the recursive case, instead of just returning the remainder of the list passed into the function, return the current element followed by the remainder of the list. The base cases still remain simple:

```
add :: Eq a => a -> Bag a -> Bag a
add x (ListBag []) = ListBag [(x, 1)] -- first base case
add x (ListBag (x', n):xs)
  | x == x'   = ListBag $ (x', n + 1) : xs -- second base case
  | otherwise = let ListBag rest = add x (ListBag xs) in ListBag $ (x', n) : rest
```

You have to use the `let` statement to get the list out of the `ListBag` so that you can put the tuple you didn't touch back in front of it.

When thinking about recursion like this, I prefer not to think of it like a series of steps but rather to consider each case separately. In each case, we want to return the *entire* `ListBag` we were given. So we need to cons the tuple we're working on with the rest of the list. In the recursive case, we get the rest of the list from a recursive call; in the second base case we do not have to call the function again.

So, by returning the entire bag at each step, we maintain the entire list at the end of all the recursion.

I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Had to accept Daniel's answer as he was first in, sorry. But excellent response! I'm doing exam revision, so I'm trying to get this done as a way of learning. I'll have a go at the add implementation and might post it here to see what you think

Comment: @SeanA If you think Tikhon's answer is better, you should accept it instead of mine. =)

Comment: @TikhonJelvis

add :: Eq a => a -> (Bag a) -> (Bag a)
add element (ListBag []) = ListBag [(element,1)]
add element (ListBag [(element',n)]) = ListBag[(element',n+1)]
add element (ListBag ((element',n):rest)) = add element (ListBag rest)

I have this now, but i lose track of the list when it matches, so only returns a list with the element that ive just added. How would you implement this?

Comment: Think of the end result you want. Particularly in the recursive case: the result of the recursive call should still preserve the element of the list you're skipping over, so that the final result still contains it. Also, the `ListBag [(x', n)]` should really be `ListBag ((x', n):xs)` so that you match the rest of the list with `xs`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Tikhom, I've come back to this problem but still can't find a good soluion. Could you provide some code? This seems to be a rpoblem I have with a lot of my Haskell... keeping the list while you iterate over it and joining them back up at the end. Thank you :)